# Identify where a python script was launched from

Tags: python

I was looking through methods of handling arguments when I realised that I'm actually looking to do something slightly different.

Basically I am writing my python3 script in Jupyter as `foo.ipynb` to test it on small datasets, and to share it with my team easily, but I will also be exporting the script to `foo.py` and running it on our cluster for the bigger datasets. I would like it to have some different behaviours, like getting a filepath from an argument or not, depending on how the script was ran.

Is there any way for a python script to know if it was ran in a Jupyter notebook or through the command line? Our cluster uses slurm, so `foo.py` will be called from a bash script, is there any way to handle that as well?

Comment: can't you just check the host name and use this to discriminate the behavior? e.g. with `socket.gethostname() `

Comment: @MarcoP I am unfamiliar with this function. How about writing it into an answer with code so I can see how it works?

Comment: @yvesonline just did it, I was waiting to see it MarcoP had any other suggesitons but yours worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__file__` ([Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__)).

When calling `foo.py` directly via `python foo.py` then `__file__` will be set, e.g.: `foo.py` with only a `print(__file__)` will output `foo.py`.

If called in Jupyter it won't be set.

Regarding slurm, I'd recommend passing in another argument to your script to distinguish this, e.g. `foo.py --slurm` with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

---

Code Addendum:

```
if '__file__' in locals():
    print(__file__)
else:
    print('__file__ not set')
```